# Watch dynamically allocated two dimensional array in Netbeans

Tags: c, arrays, netbeans

How can i watch a dynamically allocated two dimensional int array in Netbeans?

This is my C code:

```
ppPositions = (int**) calloc(nElements, sizeof(int*));
    for(i = 0; i < nElements; i++) {
        ppPositions[i] = (int*) calloc(MAX_NUM, sizeof(int));
    }
}
```

And this is the watch i'm using in the variables window:

```
*((ppPositions)+0)@4
```

This code works with a string array (matrix of chars) but not with a matrix of integers :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simple enough.

Instead of using:

```
*((ppPositions)+0)@4
```

i just need to use this as a watch:

```
**((ppPositions)+0)@4
```